# Limit of Series of Distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $\displaystyle \langle \psi_k,\phi\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(kx)\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x,\ \phi \in \mathcal{C}_c^\infty(\Omega),\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}$ open. That means $\phi$ is a testfunction.

I want to compute

$\displaystyle \lim_{k\to \infty}\langle \psi_k,\phi\rangle$ and also $\displaystyle \lim_{k\to \infty}\langle \psi^2_k,\phi\rangle$

I know that for the fouriertransform $\mathcal{F}$ as a unitary operator it holds true that

$\langle \mathcal{F}\psi_k,\phi\rangle = \langle \psi_k,\mathcal{F}^{-1}\phi\rangle$

Using this I compute the inverse fourier transform of $\sin(kx)$ which yields

$\displaystyle i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\delta(k+x)-i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\delta(k-x)$

then I get

$\displaystyle \lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathcal{F}^{-1}\phi(x) -i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathcal{F}^{-1}\phi(-x)\,\mathrm{d}x$

which does not really help. Although I could solve the first (non-squared) one by using integration by parts (limit is then zero), I could not solve the squared version of it by using this technique, so I tried another strategy, which is the one I showed above.

Comment: No big deal, but shouldn't it be $\langle \mathcal{F}\psi_k,\phi\rangle = \langle \psi_k,\mathcal{F}\phi\rangle$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\sin^2(k\,x)=\frac{1-\cos(2\,k\,x)}{2}.
$$

Comment: I would then obtain that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\langle \psi^2_k,\phi\rangle = \| \phi\|_{L^1}$, is this correct?

Comment: No, the limit would be $$\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\phi(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: Yes, of course, I missed out on the factor and the absolute... Do you know if my other solution is correct (the non squared one)? Also do you have any idea how to complete my other approach via FT?

Comment: Why bother with the Fourier transform? By the way, the $\sin(k\,x)$ case is just the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the RL lemma also hold for inverse FT?

Comment: If $f$ is integrable, that $\lim_{\xi\to\infty}\hat f(\xi)=0$. If both $f$ and $\hat f$ are integrable, then also  $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your method will work fine; $(\hat \psi, \phi) = (\psi, \hat \phi)$ gives
$$(\sin^2 k x, \phi) =
\frac 1 4 (2 \delta(w) - \delta(w - 2 k) - \delta(w + 2 k), \hat \phi) \to
\frac {\hat \phi(0)} 2 =
\left( \frac 1 2, \phi \right).$$
The other two delta terms tend to zero because $\hat \phi$ is a function of rapid decay.